# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

Tags: php, веб-программирование, wamp

Ошибка в строке 54 (в коде показано) Запрос к БД перепроверял, всё корректно, поле таблицы, заголовки колонок - всё без ошибок.

```
public static function getProductsListByCategory($categoryId = false, $page = 1) {
    if ($categoryId) {

        $page = intval($page);
        $offset = ($page - 1) * self::SHOW_BY_DEFAULT; //Формула для реализации постраничного вывода всех товаров

        $db = Db::getConnection();            
        $products = array();
        $result = $db->query("SELECT id, name, price, image, is_new FROM product "
                . "WHERE status = '1' AND category_id = '$categoryId' "
                . "ORDER BY id DESC "                
                . "LIMIT ".self::SHOW_BY_DEFAULT
                . 'OFFSET '.$offset);

        $i = 0;
        while ($row = $result->fetch()) { //строка 54
            $products[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
            $products[$i]['name'] = $row['name'];
            $products[$i]['image'] = $row['image'];
            $products[$i]['price'] = $row['price'];
            $products[$i]['is_new'] = $row['is_new'];
            $i++;
        }

        return $products;       
    }
}
```

Comment: Данный вопрос был задан и отвечен много раз. Из документации http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.query.php#refsect1-pdo.query-returnvalues `PDO::query() возвращает объект PDOStatement или FALSE, если запрос выполнить не удалось.`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Запрос к БД перепроверял

А `$result` проверить? В сообщении об ошибке совершенно ясно сказано, что переменная не является объектом. Поэтому:

```
$result = $db->query(...);
if( !$result ) {
    /* анализируем ошибку */
}
```

Comment: А из-за чего переменная может не являться объектом? Эту информацию можно узнать, грамотно проанализировав ошибку? Как проанализировать ошибку в данном случае? Запрос к БД, вроде, корректный, в таблице тоже порядок, почему же данные, записывающиеся в $result не объект?

Comment: P.S. var_dump($result); //boolean false

Comment: Ну так если `$result === false`, то очевидно, что запрос отработал с ошибкой. Как анализировать ошибку - обратитесь к документации по вашему драйверу БД (класс `Db`?). Или человеку, который его писал, если это самоделка.

Comment: класс Db очень прост    class Db
{
    
    public static function getConnection()
    {
        $paramsPath = ROOT . '/config/db_params.php';
        $params = include($paramsPath);
        

        $dsn = "mysql:host={$params['host']};dbname={$params['dbname']}";
        $db = new PDO($dsn, $params['user'], $params['password']);
        $db->exec("set names utf8");
        
        return $db;
    }

}

Comment: `class Db
{
    
    public static function getConnection()
    {
        $paramsPath = ROOT . '/config/db_params.php';
        $params = include($paramsPath);
        

        $dsn = "mysql:host={$params['host']};dbname={$params['dbname']}";
        $db = new PDO($dsn, $params['user'], $params['password']);
        $db->exec("set names utf8");
        
        return $db;
    }

}`

Comment: Включение '$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);'  тоже не прояснило ситуацию. Ошибки:

Comment: 'Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1327 Undeclared variable: 10OFFSET' in C:\wamp\www\models\Product.php on line 51
( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1327 Undeclared variable: 10OFFSET in C:\wamp\www\models\Product.php on line 51'

Comment: То есть, PDO ругается на последнюю часть запроса '. 'OFFSET '.$offset);'